# how to calculate the contribute and weight of component in negative case?

Tags: python, math

I have some timeseries sequences, as the topic, I would like to calculate the contribute as well the weight of component. Specifically, the formula as below

```
    Y_t = a_t + beta_1 * b_t - beta_2 * c_t

    Y_{t+1} = a_{t+1} + beta_1 * b_{t+1} - beta_2 * c_{t+1}
    ...
    Y_{t+n} = a_{t+n} + beta_1 * b_{t+n} - beta_2 * c_{t+n}
```

I want to find the contribute of the change in each component a, b, c to the change in Y `Y_{t+1} - Y_t`, and calculate the weight of them?

So, how to solve this problem using Python? Note that we have both positive and negative value

Thank all!